# Why does a non-current TAB event not execute?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

Use the Google extension to open both tabs at the same time and inject the following code into both pages:

```
window.onload = function(){
    alert('I did...');
}
```

But only the current TAB says 'I did... ', switch to another TAB and do not execute. This question has been bothering me for a long time. I hope a gentleman can answer it for me. Thank you.

Comment: Chrome doesn't display `alert` in inactive tabs. This is the [intended behavior](https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/6477774290157568).

Comment: Maybe the window is load before you insert the script? You could check with`if (document.readyState === "complete") { alert('I did...') } else { /* window.onload = ... ...*/}` ... I would also try adding an alert without any onload to see if it works at all in the second tab.

Comment: You mean the Google browser does not allow `alert` operations on non-current tabs?